# distributing independent python app to other machines

Tags: python, distribution, cx-freeze

I created independent python app using cxfreeze under linux and can run it other machines without python and other dependencies.

But while doing it for **mac OS X**, **in other machines** the **app searches** for the following **python installed location** which actually present in the machine where it is frozen.

"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.1/Python"

How to execute this app without this dependency?

Answer (score 1):

Try py2app for Mac OS X.  (And py2exe for Windows.)